# How to convert raw html (string) to htmlDocument in Java

Tags: java

I have html source code as simple string in java class. I have to convert it to htmlDocument (de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.HTMLDocument) object (to use it in boilerpipe later). How can I convert a string to htmlDocument.
Following is the code

```
package tmp;

import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import de.l3s.boilerpipe.document.TextDocument;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.CommonExtractors;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.HTMLDocument;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.HTMLFetcher;

public class Tmp {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String url = "https://jang.com.pk/latest/444637-dna-was-taken-from-the-suspect-taken-from-mardan-asmaa";
        String str = HTMLFetcher.fetch(new URL(url)).toString();


//      HTMLDocument htmlDoc= new HTMLDocument(str, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument(str);

//      final HTMLDocument htmlDoc = HTMLFetcher.fetch(new URL(url));
        TextDocument doc = new BoilerpipeSAXInput(htmlDoc.toInputSource()).getTextDocument();
        String content = CommonExtractors.ARTICLE_EXTRACTOR.getText(doc);
        System.out.println(content);
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking source  code of [`HTMLDocument`](https://github.com/gregbayer/boilerpipe/blob/master/boilerpipe-core/src/main/de/l3s/boilerpipe/sax/HTMLDocument.java) gives you the answer.

It have a cool constructor to take html string.

```
public HTMLDocument(final String data) {
        Charset cs = Charset.forName("utf-8");
        this.data = data.getBytes(cs);
        this.charset = cs;
    }
```

So

```
HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument(htmlStr);
```

Comment: I got message that constractor is not defined for string input

Answer (score 1):

Like this you can create the HTMLDocument.

```
Charset cs = Charset.forName("utf-8");
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = new HTMLDocument(str.getBytes(cs),cs);
```